# Оптимизация медленно выполняющегося MySQL запроса

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица и в ней 15000 записей.
Скорость выполнения запроса составляет целых 0.5 секунды.
Как подобное можно оптимизировать?
Запрос:

```sql
SELECT `cat`.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM `board`
        WHERE `board`.`podcat` = `cat`.`id`
          AND `status` = '1'
          AND `timesrok` > '".intval($realtime)."') AS `count_board`
FROM `cat`
WHERE `ref` = '".intval($cat['id'])."'
ORDER BY `realid` ASC
```

Структура таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `board` (
`id` int(11) auto_increment,
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
`podcat` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`name_translate` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`file` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`foto` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`fotka` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`screen` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`size` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`size_convert` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`price` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`telefon` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`contact` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`send` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`city` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`skype` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
`timeupdate` int(11) NOT NULL,
`timesrok` int(11) NOT NULL,
`top` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`toptime` int(11) NOT NULL,
`srochno` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`timesrochno` int(11) NOT NULL,
`vydelit` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`timevydelit` int(11) NOT NULL,
`torg` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`by` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`free` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`status` int(1) NOT NULL default '2',
`convert` int(1) NOT NULL default '2',
`type` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`activation` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`count` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`text` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
`prosmotrov` int(11) NOT NULL,
`lat` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`lng` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`watermark` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

И второй

```
--
-- Структура таблицы `cat`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cat`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cat` (
`id` int(11) auto_increment,
`ref` int(11) NOT NULL,
`realid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`translate` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`keywords` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
`logo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: [EXPLAIN](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/EXPLAIN.html)

Comment: EXPLAIN http://joxi.ru/DmBxlQ0uZppKAP

Comment: Еще не плохо бы структуру таблицы ([`show create table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html)) увидеть. У вас индексы что ли отсутствуют?

Comment: Добавил структуру в первый пост.

Comment: Все поля не нужны были, достаточно было только тех, что в запросе участвуют. И вторую бы таблицу тоже привели бы, хотя и так видно: индексов нет. Надо хотя бы на `podcat` и `status` повесить индекс. В таблице `cat` тоже бы индекс на `ref` не помешал бы. Но для точного ответа надо бы знать остальные выборки и как часто они выполняются. Поэтому вам самому придется решать где и на что индексы вешать. но 0.5с не так уж и много, особенно если запрос выполняется не часто.

Comment: Запрос выполняется часто. 
Добавил индексы на podcat и status. Не помогло. Также 0.5с.

Comment: Я сомневаюсь, что смогу в комментарии (или даже в ответе) рассказать об индексах, если вы ничего о них не знаете. Я бы посоветовал вам прочитать [эту книгу](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do). Есть ли 3е издание на русском не знаю, второе точно есть, но оно уже устарело, хотя основы там расписаны хорошо. В общем суть следующая: если индексов нет, то mysql приходится считывать каждую строку на диске и проверять условия. Если есть нужные индексы, то они скорее всего хранятся в памяти, поэтому эти проверки проходят быстрее и мы точно знаем какие записи надо извлекать.

Comment: С индексами разобрался, проставил на podcat, status, timesrok таблицы board и на ref таблицы cat. Теперь 0.1 вместо 0.5. Ещё как-то можно оптимизировать?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23319/discussion-between-bopoh-and-vitagame).